# Photoshop: Automating vector art placement into multiple PSD mockup files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, smartobject

I have a small print-on-demand clothing company, and spend a lot of time creating mockups for t-shirt designs. I'm wondering if it's possible to place a "linked" smart object or vector object into multiple PSD mockup files in a folder, that would update automatically when it's updated. For example, I'm imagining 10 PSD files in a folder (t-shirt mockups), and all of the files had a smart object (or similar) that could be updated once and the updated would be reflected in all 10 files.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

In the `File` menu you'll find `Place Linked...` command that places a linked smart object.

If you have .psd(s) with the linked file opened, the placed objects will update automatically. If you open them later, there will be a warning sign on the obsolete placed layer. Click with the right mouse button will reveal `Update (All) Modified Content` options.

[image]

If you want to automatically update a lot of files you can record this step as an Action and run the Action of a folder of images or opened images using [Image Processor](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html) or `Automate > Batch..` command.